# why hub object is undefined

Tags: webforms, signalr

why hub object is undefined below is the code, I have owin, hub all the classes in my project, howevery am not able to call hub methods?

```
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->


    <script src="../scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/signalr/signalr/hubs"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        //why hub is not created matrixHub = undefined
        var matrixHub = $.connection.MyHub;

        // TODO, callbacks and hub invoker

        $.connection.hub.start();
        debugger;
    });
</script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your capitalization is wrong, it should be

```
var matrixHub = $.connection.myHub;
```

*IF* your hub class is named MyHub : Hub

The reason for this has to do with how the javascript for the hub is generated, all methods and the hub itself are all created with camelCase names on a javascript client.

Comment: please read this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254160/how-to-create-a-signalr-hub-proxy-in-javascript-having-hubs-in-class-library

Comment: after too much time I got your point can you tell me the logic? why it is necessary any documentation ?

Comment: Added the reason in the answer for completeness

Comment: Where should I keep my owing class? web project or class library?

Comment: its in your class library, Your startup class sets all that up.

Comment: To clarify, it needs to be in the same place as your hub class.