# how to create a signalR hub proxy in javascript, having hubs in class library?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr-2

currently, am working on chat application using signalR and agsxmpp library, I have seen many examples how to create a proxy of hub in javascript. however, my architecture is differ from these examples.

I have class library and a web project(web forms)

Hubs are written in class library, and java script exists in web project, I want to create proxy of hub(written in class library) in java script I have tried a lot. but couldn't find a solution.

I have read owin(startup.cs) but still not a  clear picture, where should I keep my owin class, in web project or class library?

I have defined my scenario in detail here
when I don't have a class library it works fine.
[image: when I don't have a class library it works fine]

when I have a class library.

[image: when I have class library in my project]

Comment: How does you hub class on the server look like? Maybe this is just a casing issue (e.g. the class on the server side is called ConnectionHub) and you should just use `.connectionHub`?